# Sacar una lista dentro de una lista sabiendo solo un elemento de la lista anidada

Tags: python, lista

```
lista=[[burro, cabeza, dedo], [manzana, pera, cebolla], [limón, brazo, piña]]
```

me gustaría obtener la lista que contiene '**manzana**'e imprimirla
Gracias.

Comment: Esta pregunta debería incluir más detalles para clarificar el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se utiliza la expresión "if A in B" para determinar si un elemento está dentro de una lista. En tal caso, retornamos la sublista.

La función `buscar` retorna la sublista que contiene la palabra, o `None` si no la encuentra.

```
lista=[["burro", "cabeza", "dedo"], ["manzana", "pera", "cebolla"], ["limón", "brazo", "piña"]]

def buscar(lista, item):
    for elemento in lista:
        if item in elemento:
            return elemento
    return None

print(buscar(lista, "manzana"))
```

produce

```
['manzana', 'pera', 'cebolla']
```

Answer (score 0):

creo tener la solucion.

```
 lista = [['burro','cabeza','dedo'],['manzana','pera','cebolla'],['limon','brazo','piña']]
    buscar= 'manzana' #puedes cambiar esto a que se obtenga por teclado
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        for j in range(len(lista[i])):
            if(buscar==lista[i][j]):
                print(lista[i])
```

Lo probé un par de veces y me funciono

Comment: Gracias! aunque al final pude desarrollar uno parecido.